# Is it possible to persist a cookie after User login or multiple redirects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I'm working on a flow where if the `User` is not logged in, I store a `config` hash in a cookie to be retrieved after the `User` logs in so the flow can continue.

*starting controller:*

```
def index
  if current_user.nil?
    cookies.signed[:config] = config

    redirect_to new_session_path
  end
end
```

*SessionsController:*

```
def new
  cookies.signed[:config].present? # true
end

def create
  # authentication logic

  redirect_to admin_users_path
end
```

*Users controller:*

```
def index
  cookies.signed[:config].present? # false
end
```

I can retrieve said cookie from the `SessionsController` `new` action after the first redirect, but after the `User` logs in and is redirected again to the final destination (`create` action), the cookie seems to be deleted because `cookies.signed[:config]` returns `nil`

I'm not deleting the cookie explicitly, and I've tried using `session[:config] = config` instead of `cookies.signed` but to the same result.

Is it possible to persist a cookie through multiple redirects or a `User` login?

Or do I have to set the cookie in each controller action so it is passed along until where I actually use it?

**EDIT:** The problem was that our generic login controller was under the subdomain `app.ourapp.com` while a logged in `User` was redirected to `business.ourapp.com`.

When no domain is specified during cookie creation, the `request.domain` is used by default so the cookie was never created for `business.ourapp.com` .

The fix was to pass a `domain` argument in the cookie creation so it was created for both `app.ourapp.com` and `business.ourapp.com` (`cookies.signed(:cookie_name, domain: "ourapp.com"`)

Comment: Rather than add **EDIT** I found the answer. Either answer your own question, which given that your question is reasonably stated, would be an acceptable action or remove the question. Very rarely, if ever, will someone come across a question and expect it to contain an answer (they will look in the answers section for that), so as it sits this post does not lend well to the character of SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that our generic login controller was under the subdomain `app.ourapp.com` while a logged in `User` was redirected to `business.ourapp.com`.

When no domain is specified during cookie creation, the `request.domain` is used by default so the cookie was never created for `business.ourapp.com` .

The fix was to pass a domain argument in the cookie creation so it was created for both `app.ourapp.com` and `business.ourapp.com` (`cookies.signed(:cookie_name, domain: "ourapp.com"`)